# Convert word tables to text with Manual Intervention

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to convert some tables to text but i need ***manual intervention***.
I am to select the table by loop but not able to stop it. 
I need to stop the loop at each table and select yes button to convert it or skip button to skip to next table.

I have tried the code below .

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
Dim tbl As Table
Dim t As Integer

For Each tbl In ActiveDocument.Tables
If tbl.Cell(1, 1).Range.Text Like "*Family number*" Then
tbl.ConvertToText
Activetable().Select
Call CommandButton4_Click


End If

Next tbl
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
Dim tbl As Table
Dim t As Integer
For t = 1 To ActiveDocument.Tables.Count
ActiveDocument.Tables(t).Select

Call CommandButton5_Click
Next t

End Sub
```

I just want to manual click yes to convert the current selected table into text or click skip to select the next table in loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can simply use a `MsgBox` to ask and skip a Table.**

Use this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

Dim tbl As Table

For Each tbl In ActiveDocument.Tables
    If tbl.Cell(1, 1).Range.Text Like "*Family number*" Then

        tbl.Select
        If MsgBox("Skip Table ?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then
            tbl.ConvertToText
        End If
    End If

Next tbl
End Sub
```

---

**Demo:**

[image]